# Reddy Mikks new objective formation problem operations research

Tags: operations-research

Am I thinking of the correct solution to the problem attached in Figure below of the Introduction to Operations Research book by Taha? I describe my approach to the problem in the attachment.

x->quantity of exterior paint bought more than 2 tons
y->quantity of exterior paint bought less than 2 tons
z->profit

I am very new to operations research. Can anyone tell me what the correct solution to this problem should be?

[image: Problem statement 1]

[image: problem statement 2]

[image: My objective function]